# Access violation when mouse enters custom TPanel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a custom `TPanel` that handles `WMNCHitTest`. At runtime, when mouse enters the panel, I get the following AV:

> Project ClientDatasetEditor.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00405219: read of address Ox0000000c'

The Call Stack shows:

```
> :00405219 SysGetMem + $30
• :0040b7c6 @DynArraySetLength + $A
• :005394e7 TWinControl.MainWndproc + $2F
• :004c945a StdWndProc + $16
• :76ff7694 user32.CaIINextt-iookEx + 0x97
• :76ff8baa; C: \WIND0WSysWOW64iser32.dII
• :76ff8468; C:\WINDOWSysW0W64iser32.dII
• :76ff9c40 user32.DispatchMessageW + Ox1O
```

Follows `WMNCHitTest` handle:

```
procedure tExGraphicControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: tWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;

  if not (csDesigning in  ComponentState) or
         (msOver      in fMouseStates   )    then Exit;

  if  Message.Msg = WM_NCRButtonUp then begin
      fMouseStates := [msLeftUp];
      Exit                      ;
  end;

  if  Message.Msg = WM_NCMBUTTONUP then begin
      fMouseStates := [msLeftUp];
      Exit                      ;
  end;

  if IsMouseOverControl (Self) then begin
     fMouseStates := [msOver, msMove];
     if  Assigned (fOnMouseEvent) then
          fOnMouseEvent (Self, fMouseStates);
  end;
end;
```

Any idea about what's causing the AV?

Comment: Did you really include the upper part of the call stack?

Comment: @Sertac. Yes, it is all there.

Comment: I've noticed that the AV is raised when I include the `inherited` clause. But if I take it off, then the `OnClick` event stops responding.

Comment: Interesting that it looks incomplete. You have to put a breakpoint on inherited and trace into it, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea what is causing the AV?

An access violation in `GetMem` is caused by a heap corruption. You have a defect in your program that is corrupting the heap.

The best way for you to track the fault down is to use the FastMM memory manager in full debug mode. This should, hopefully, tell you the point in the code that corrupts the heap.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If it is so, how can I detect what is corrupting the heap? Any suggestion?

Comment: Follow the advice in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: The address looks like accessing something of a nil something, but maybe you're right.

Comment: @Sertac It's in GetMem. Given that we take as given that GetMem is correct, what else could it be. What causes GetMem to AV other than heap corruption?

Comment: @David - that's ok, but I suspect the call stack.

Comment: It's dubious @Sertac, I agree.